# AWS Powershell to retrieve AWS account number

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

Does anyone know how to get AWS account number using AWS Powershell? Doesn't look like there's an API available for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not directly.  However, your Account ID is a part of the [Arn](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) of resources that you create... and those that are automatically created for you.  Some resources will also list you as an OwnerId.

The [Default Security Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#default-security-group) is automatically created for you in each region, and cannot be deleted.  This makes it a reliable candidate for retrieving our account Id.

Example:

```
PS C:/> $accountId = @(get-ec2securitygroup -GroupNames "default")[0].OwnerId

PS C:/> $accountId
000011112222
```

Comment: Great answer above, thanks. I noticed that you can get the account alias which in my case was what I needed. To do so use Get-IamAccountAlias

Answer (score 12):

Nice and simple

`(Get-STSCallerIdentity).Account`

...or

`(Get-STSCallerIdentity -Region [your_aws_region]).Account`

Comment: IMHO, this is a better answer.

Comment: This is the right answer. You can get a list of accounts in your organization with Get-ORGAccountList

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to comment on the other provided answer, so I'll have to offer my own solution as a slight modification.

I do believe the OwnerId on all groups will be the Account Id.  However you may not have a "default" group.  I recommend leaving out the -GroupNames "default".  Also, I'm showing my example using a SAML token, as that is our case coming in with AD authorization.

```
$awsAccountNumber = (get-ec2securitygroup -ProfileName saml -Region us-west-2)[0].OwnerId
```

Hopefully that will be of some use.

Answer (score 1):

I use Get-STSCallerIdentity.
Here is a code snippet that I use:

```
    foreach ($ProfileName in $Profiles){
    if ($ProfileName -match 'gov') { 
        Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration -ProfileName $ProfileName -Region us-gov-east-1
        $STSCallerIdentity = Get-STSCallerIdentity
    }
    else { 
        Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration -ProfileName $ProfileName -Region us-east-1 
        $STSCallerIdentity = Get-STSCallerIdentity
    }
```